# ddrescue: Write error: Invalid argument

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, ddrescue

I'm trying to recover my data from a 500 gigabyte hard drive that is failing. I'm attempting to use ddrescue with the syntax shown in the output below, but I keep getting the error in the title. What can I do to fix this, or bypass it?

```
root@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/MacosBackup/1# ddrescue -d /dev/sdc2 test.img test.logfile
GNU ddrescue 1.23
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
     ipos:    4297 MB, non-trimmed:    3866 kB,  current rate:       0 B/s
     opos:    4297 MB, non-scraped:        0 B,  average rate:   6659 kB/s
non-tried:  496746 MB,  bad-sector:        0 B,    error rate:       0 B/s
  rescued:    2497 MB,   bad areas:        0,        run time:      6m 14s
pct rescued:    0.50%, read errors:       59,  remaining time:      6h 29m
                              time since last successful read:         15s
Copying non-tried blocks... Pass 1 (forwards)
ddrescue: Write error: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Is the filesystem for the current directory mounted read/write? How much free space? Could you 'cd $HOME;ddrescue -d /dev/sdc2 /media/ubuntu/MacosBackup/1/test.img test.logfille`?

Comment: The filesystem is mounted RW, and it has over 900 gigabytes of free space, while the drive I'm imaging is around 500 gigabytes. I would totally do that command you said, but I'm running this on a live session, I only have about 4 gigabytes of free space on my USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I made a mistake while formatting the drive I was storing the image on. I accidentally formatted it as `FAT32`, which incurs a 4GB file size limit for the setting I selected. Oops!

After reformatting as `EXT4`, the size limit is nolonger in place, and I've successfully recovered about 5% so far!

Comment: I will select this as the answer in 2 days, seems I have a delay before it will let me.